# Qt Суммарный ProgressBar по стандартному примеру http

Tags: c++, qt, progress-bar

Пытаюсь на основе примера `http` реализовать `progressBar` для окна загрузки файлов, сейчас он работает для каждого файла отдельно.Хотелось бы чтобы полоса прогресс была единая для всех скачиваемых файлов от 0 до 100, а не каждого файла по отдельности. Вот код:

**httpwindow.h**

```
#ifndef HTTPWINDOW_H
#define HTTPWINDOW_H

#include <QProgressDialog>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QFile;
class QLabel;
class QLineEdit;
class QPushButton;
class QSslError;
class QAuthenticator;
class QNetworkReply;
class QCheckBox;

QT_END_NAMESPACE

class ProgressDialog : public QProgressDialog {
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit ProgressDialog(const QUrl &url, QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

public slots:
void networkReplyProgress(qint64 bytesRead, qint64 totalBytes);
};

class HttpWindow : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit HttpWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

void startRequest(const QUrl &requestedUrl);

private slots:
void downloadFile();
void cancelDownload();
void httpFinished();
void httpReadyRead();
void enableDownloadButton();
void slotAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator *);
#ifndef QT_NO_SSL
void sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,const QList<QSslError> &errors);
#endif

private:
QFile *openFileForWrite(const QString &fileName);

QLabel *statusLabel;
QLineEdit *urlLineEdit;
QPushButton *downloadButton;
QCheckBox *launchCheckBox;
QLineEdit *defaultFileLineEdit;
QLineEdit *downloadDirectoryLineEdit;

QUrl url;
QNetworkAccessManager qnam;
QNetworkReply *reply;
QFile *file;
bool httpRequestAborted;
};

#endif
```

**httpwindow.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QUrl>

#include "httpwindow.h"
#include "ui_authenticationdialog.h"

#ifndef QT_NO_SSL
static const char defaultUrl[] = "https://qt-project.org/";
#else
static const char defaultUrl[] = "http://qt-project.org/";
#endif
static const char defaultFileName[] = "index.html";

ProgressDialog::ProgressDialog(const QUrl &url, QWidget *parent)
: QProgressDialog(parent)
{
setWindowTitle(tr("Download Progress"));
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
setLabelText(tr("Downloading %1.").arg(url.toDisplayString()));
setMinimum(0);
setValue(0);
setMinimumDuration(0);
}

 void ProgressDialog::networkReplyProgress(qint64 bytesRead, qint64 totalBytes)
{
setMaximum(totalBytes);
setValue(bytesRead);
}

HttpWindow::HttpWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QDialog(parent)
, statusLabel(new QLabel(tr("Please enter the URL of a file you want to download.\n\n"), this))
, urlLineEdit(new QLineEdit(defaultUrl))
, downloadButton(new QPushButton(tr("Download")))
, launchCheckBox(new QCheckBox("Launch file"))
, defaultFileLineEdit(new QLineEdit(defaultFileName))
, downloadDirectoryLineEdit(new QLineEdit)
, reply(Q_NULLPTR)
, file(Q_NULLPTR)
, httpRequestAborted(false)
{
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
setWindowTitle(tr("HTTP"));

connect(&qnam, &QNetworkAccessManager::authenticationRequired,
        this, &HttpWindow::slotAuthenticationRequired);
#ifndef QT_NO_SSL
connect(&qnam, &QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors,
        this, &HttpWindow::sslErrors);
#endif

QFormLayout *formLayout = new QFormLayout;
urlLineEdit->setClearButtonEnabled(true);
connect(urlLineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged,
        this, &HttpWindow::enableDownloadButton);
formLayout->addRow(tr("&URL:"), urlLineEdit);
QString downloadDirectory = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation);
if (downloadDirectory.isEmpty() || !QFileInfo(downloadDirectory).isDir())
    downloadDirectory = QDir::currentPath();
downloadDirectoryLineEdit->setText(QDir::toNativeSeparators(downloadDirectory));
formLayout->addRow(tr("&Download directory:"), downloadDirectoryLineEdit);
formLayout->addRow(tr("Default &file:"), defaultFileLineEdit);
launchCheckBox->setChecked(true);
formLayout->addRow(launchCheckBox);

QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
mainLayout->addLayout(formLayout);

mainLayout->addItem(new QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding));

statusLabel->setWordWrap(true);
mainLayout->addWidget(statusLabel);

downloadButton->setDefault(true);
connect(downloadButton, &QAbstractButton::clicked, this, &HttpWindow::downloadFile);
QPushButton *quitButton = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"));
quitButton->setAutoDefault(false);
connect(quitButton, &QAbstractButton::clicked, this, &QWidget::close);
QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox;
buttonBox->addButton(downloadButton, QDialogButtonBox::ActionRole);
buttonBox->addButton(quitButton, QDialogButtonBox::RejectRole);
mainLayout->addWidget(buttonBox);

urlLineEdit->setFocus();
}

void HttpWindow::startRequest(const QUrl &requestedUrl)
{
url = requestedUrl;
httpRequestAborted = false;

reply = qnam.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &HttpWindow::httpFinished);
connect(reply, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &HttpWindow::httpReadyRead);

ProgressDialog *progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(url, this);
progressDialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
connect(progressDialog, &QProgressDialog::canceled, this, &HttpWindow::cancelDownload);
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, progressDialog, &ProgressDialog::networkReplyProgress);
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, progressDialog, &ProgressDialog::hide);
progressDialog->show();

statusLabel->setText(tr("Downloading %1...").arg(url.toString()));
}

void HttpWindow::downloadFile()
{
const QString urlSpec = urlLineEdit->text().trimmed();
if (urlSpec.isEmpty())
    return;

const QUrl newUrl = QUrl::fromUserInput(urlSpec);
if (!newUrl.isValid()) {
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Error"),
                             tr("Invalid URL: %1: %2").arg(urlSpec, newUrl.errorString()));
    return;
}

QString fileName = newUrl.fileName();
if (fileName.isEmpty())
    fileName = defaultFileLineEdit->text().trimmed();
if (fileName.isEmpty())
    fileName = defaultFileName;
QString downloadDirectory = QDir::cleanPath(downloadDirectoryLineEdit->text().trimmed());
if (!downloadDirectory.isEmpty() && QFileInfo(downloadDirectory).isDir())
    fileName.prepend(downloadDirectory + '/');
if (QFile::exists(fileName)) {
    if (QMessageBox::question(this, tr("Overwrite Existing File"),
                              tr("There already exists a file called %1 in "
                                 "the current directory. Overwrite?").arg(fileName),
                              QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No, QMessageBox::No)
        == QMessageBox::No)
        return;
    QFile::remove(fileName);
}

file = openFileForWrite(fileName);
if (!file)
    return;

downloadButton->setEnabled(false);

// schedule the request
startRequest(newUrl);
}

QFile *HttpWindow::openFileForWrite(const QString &fileName)
{
QScopedPointer<QFile> file(new QFile(fileName));
if (!file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Error"),
                             tr("Unable to save the file %1: %2.")
                             .arg(QDir::toNativeSeparators(fileName),
                                  file->errorString()));
    return Q_NULLPTR;
}
return file.take();
}

void HttpWindow::cancelDownload()
{
statusLabel->setText(tr("Download canceled."));
httpRequestAborted = true;
reply->abort();
downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
}

void HttpWindow::httpFinished()
{
QFileInfo fi;
if (file) {
    fi.setFile(file->fileName());
    file->close();
    delete file;
    file = Q_NULLPTR;
}

if (httpRequestAborted) {
    reply->deleteLater();
    reply = Q_NULLPTR;
    return;
}

if (reply->error()) {
    QFile::remove(fi.absoluteFilePath());
    statusLabel->setText(tr("Download failed:\n%1.").arg(reply->errorString()));
    downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
    reply->deleteLater();
    reply = Q_NULLPTR;
    return;
}

const QVariant redirectionTarget = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);

reply->deleteLater();
reply = Q_NULLPTR;

if (!redirectionTarget.isNull()) {
    const QUrl redirectedUrl = url.resolved(redirectionTarget.toUrl());
    if (QMessageBox::question(this, tr("Redirect"),
                              tr("Redirect to %1 ?").arg(redirectedUrl.toString()),
                              QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::No) {
        downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
        return;
    }
    file = openFileForWrite(fi.absoluteFilePath());
    if (!file) {
        downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
        return;
    }
    startRequest(redirectedUrl);
    return;
}

statusLabel->setText(tr("Downloaded %1 bytes to %2\nin\n%3")
                     .arg(fi.size()).arg(fi.fileName(), QDir::toNativeSeparators(fi.absolutePath())));
if (launchCheckBox->isChecked())
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fi.absoluteFilePath()));
downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
}

void HttpWindow::httpReadyRead()
{
// this slot gets called every time the QNetworkReply has new data.
// We read all of its new data and write it into the file.
// That way we use less RAM than when reading it at the finished()
// signal of the QNetworkReply
if (file)
    file->write(reply->readAll());
}

void HttpWindow::enableDownloadButton()
{
downloadButton->setEnabled(!urlLineEdit->text().isEmpty());
}

void HttpWindow::slotAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator *authenticator)
{
QDialog authenticationDialog;
Ui::Dialog ui;
ui.setupUi(&authenticationDialog);
authenticationDialog.adjustSize();
ui.siteDescription->setText(tr("%1 at %2").arg(authenticator->realm(), url.host()));

// Did the URL have information? Fill the UI
// This is only relevant if the URL-supplied credentials were wrong
ui.userEdit->setText(url.userName());
ui.passwordEdit->setText(url.password());

if (authenticationDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    authenticator->setUser(ui.userEdit->text());
    authenticator->setPassword(ui.passwordEdit->text());
}
}

#ifndef QT_NO_SSL
void HttpWindow::sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,const QList<QSslError> &errors)
{
QString errorString;
foreach (const QSslError &error, errors) {
    if (!errorString.isEmpty())
        errorString += '\n';
    errorString += error.errorString();
}

if (QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("SSL Errors"),
                         tr("One or more SSL errors has occurred:\n%1").arg(errorString),
                         QMessageBox::Ignore | QMessageBox::Abort) == QMessageBox::Ignore) {
    reply->ignoreSslErrors();
}
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не хватает общего размера всех файлов, предназначенных для загрузки. Чтобы получить данную информацию вам перед началом загрузки необходимо послать HEAD запросы для всех файлов (`int QHttp::head(const QString & path)`), они вернут только заголовки, без тела. В них посмотрите размер, проссумировав получите ваш total.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую:

1. отделить сетевую часть от UI.
2. для каждого QNetworkReply выставлять setReadBufferSize, иначе Qt пишет все в память, для маленьких файлов это не критично, а если файл будет гигабайтный, то последствия очевидны. Читать после этого надо порциями по сигналу QNetworkReply::readyRead